# Let search engines know the original image

Tags: html, image, seo

I have a website with some large images. They are resized by default, but when you click on them, they open in a lightbox and become larger. I'd like to let the search engines know the original (bigger) images, instead of the smaller resize images included in the source code. Is there a way to let them index the bigger images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't decide what google chose to index (but you can make it easier for google using thepiyush13 answer), but you can tell it what NOT to index.
Put this in your robot.txt files :

```
User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /images/myImage.jpg // Put your images or directly the folder
```

Source : https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35308?hl=en
(to be adapted for other search engines)

Answer (score 0):

**Image sitemap** is the way to go for Google

> you can use Google image extensions for sitemaps to give Google more information about the images available on your pages. Image sitemap information helps Google discover images that we might not otherwise find (such as images your site reaches with JavaScript code), and allows you to indicate images on your site that you want Google to crawl and index.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
        xmlns:image="http://www.google.com/schemas/sitemap-image/1.1">
  <url>
    <loc>http://example.com/sample.html</loc>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://example.com/image.jpg</image:loc>
    </image:image>
    <image:image>
      <image:loc>http://example.com/photo.jpg</image:loc>
    </image:image>
  </url> 
</urlset>
```

source : https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/178636?hl=en